# How can I sync PDF files (and more) with my Mac and iPad?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, pdf

I know the iPad has the Book Shelf thing:

[image]

I know I can add PDF files to it - but:

- Is it possible to sync that with my Mac so I can also read them on the Mac?
- Is it possible to have them keep the same place (page / bookmark) synced?
- Would I / can I use iTunes on the mac to pick up reading where I left off on the iPad?

If it isn't possible with the the native software, are there any apps that do this?

- Also, is it somehow possible to add other reading materials (like webpages) to the bookshelf for reading later? I know that you could do something similar with Evernote but it seems odd to dump your PDF files in evernote as attachments to notes rather than having them as part of a library of some sort. Also not sure that Evernote can remember / sync your place in attached PDF files.

Comment: (I think you helped me on a math problem!!) I don't think it's possible to syn .pdfs. I thought it was possible using the iCloud, however, reading this: http://forums.applenova.com/showthread.php?t=37079 it appears that this is not possible. Anyway, I hope this helps a little. Sorry if it doesn't but good luck :)!

Answer (score 2):

The PDF files you add to the bookshelf are copied back to **iTunes** on your Mac and the can be accessed there and opened in **Preview**. Unfortunately, I don't believe your location data is synchronized.

Archiving of web pages can be done using the [*Reading List*](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_use_safari_reading_lists) function in **Safari** or using a service like [**Instapaper**](http://www.instapaper.com/).